# ¿Qué archivo de configuración usar con Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuración

Estoy utilizando Hibernate en un proyecto, quiero saber qué ventajas tiene usar un archivo sobre el otro (hibernate.cfg.xml y persistente.xml).

Comment: Tu pregunta no tiene mucho sentido. Sería mejor que expliques más sobre tu problema. Ahora, considera que hibernate.cfg.xml solo sirve si vas a utilizar Hibernate directamente, persistence.xml si es que vas a usar JPA. El data source solo es para indicar cómo obtener las conexiones a la base de datos, lo cual es agnóstico (pero necesario) para Hibernate o JPA o cualquier otro framework que te ayude con tu capa DAO.

Answer (score 1):

hibernate.cfg.xml si quieres mapear entidades,  el persistence lo utilizas para JPA, por anotaciones

Answer (score 1):

El archivo `hibernate.cfg.xml` se usa **solo** si estás usando Hibernate puro. Éste archivo tiene como finalidad establecer diferentes propiedades como:

- conexión
- dialecto
- configuraciones en transacciones (ej.  autoCommit)
- datasources
- entidades (archivos `.hbm.xml`)

Por otro lado,  `persistence.xml` es el archivo de configuración de `JPA`. Este archivo es el equivalente al `hibernate.cfg.xml` de Hibernate.